# Angular 2: is it possible to bind a var in a Dynamic Component?

Tags: angular, dynamic, data-binding, components

I'm trying to bind a var in a Dynamic Component, but when this var change in the parent, the changes are not arriving to the child component as it happens when we bind a var to a fixed component like so:

```
<child-component [myVar]="myVar"><child-component>
```

I'm trying to do it using the property instance as following, but it doesn't work, it's only passing the original value but not the changes:

```
this.componentRef.instance.myVar = this.myVar;
```

I've created a Plunker example, [Example in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8yB9gRJ0vRXHFSyroyOz?p=preview).

Comment: You have to pass the changes as well. You can pass an observable where the dynamic component can subscribe to, to get notified about changes.

Comment: If you can settle for manual update then put `this.componentRef.instance.selection = this.selection;` at the end of your `changeSelection` method.

Comment: Thanks @Ibrahim, in the example it would work but sometimes the var changes in other component, so I can't do that.

Comment: To pass an observable could be a solution, thanks @Günter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps You could make a stream from an observable & then subscribe to it in your component, thus everytime it changes your component will update the value accordingly:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class ViewToggleService {
  leftVisible:boolean=true;
  // Observable boolean source
  private leftVisibleSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  // Observable boolean stream
  leftVisibleStream$=this.leftVisibleSource.asObservable();
  constructor(){
  }
  // service command
  toggleView(viewName:string){    
      if(viewName.toString()==='leftVisible'){
         this.leftVisible=!this.leftVisible;
         this.leftVisibleSource.next(this.leftVisible);
      }
  }
}
```

then after injecting this service at your root level,inside your component you can subscribe to this stream as:

```
public leftVisible: boolean;
subscriptionLeftVisible: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {    
    this.subscriptionLeftVisible = this._viewToggleService.leftVisibleStream$.subscribe(leftVisible => {
        this.leftVisible = leftVisible;
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.